# ModalPopupExtender - popup gridview, allow user to select row and populate textbox with columns details

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

Basically, I have a textbox where a user can enter an ID from a database. To make things easier, the user can popup a GridView using a ModalPopupExtender to display all the tables columns, and they can Select a row, which then closes the modalpopupextender and sets the textbox to the row's ID column.

So far I have this:

```
     protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string testing = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        ((TextBox)dtlsInsert.FindControl("txtNom")).Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    }
```

The 'testing' string gets populated, but it doesn't seem to populate the txtNom textbox. Also, how do I close the modalpopupextender programatically?

Thanks

Comment: Are `GridView1` and `txtNom` in the same `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: No, the txtNom textbox is in the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GridView1` (and probably its container `Panel` and the associated `ModalPopupExtender`) resides in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28VS.90%29.aspx), but `txtNom` does not, `txtNom` will not be refreshed by partial postbacks triggered by `GridView1`.

There are several ways to solve this problem:

- If you can, put `txtNom` and `GridView1` in the same `UpdatePanel`.
- Put `txtNom` in another `UpdatePanel` that has its [UpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) property set to `Always`.
- Perform a full postback, by registering `GridView1` as a [PostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx) in your `UpdatePanel`.

Concerning your second question, [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) exposes `Show()` and `Hide()` methods on the server side, as well as similar `show()` and `hide()` methods on the client side.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks - I've decided to just post back when one is chosen.